# How can I run this Powershell function from a batch file on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

For some reason I am unable to get this function to execute properly from a cmd line / batch file call.

```
function streamMonitor {
[cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [string]$directoryPath,
        [string]$scriptToRestartPath
    )
... the rest of my code
}
```

After digging through tons of forums and asking chatgpt here is one of the many things have tried and I believe should totally work but isnt.

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\pathto\streamMonitor.ps1 -directoryPath "C:\pathto\stream1" -scriptToRestartPath "C:\pathto\stream1.bat"
```

When executed, the terminal doesnt throw a syntax error but the powershell script doesn't run either.

Comment: Remove the first and last lines: `function streamMonitor {` and `}` - now the script will execute instead of just defining a function

Comment: Can't say I have ever seen a programming language that executes a function without calling it.

Comment: Calling a script file (`*.ps1`) that _contains a function_ (definition)  is ineffective if your intent is to _call the contained function_. Instead, you must _dot-source_ (`. c:\path\to\script.ps1`) such a script file first - which ensures availability of the contained function in the current scope - and _then_ call the function (either directly or via `&`).
 See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a function, but you aren't calling it. Here is a version that outputs the two parameters you entered. Thanks to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for pointing out that my original script wasn't an exact fit.

Here is a version that passes the parameters in calling the script as different from the parameters used for the function.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param ($directoryPath,$scriptToRestartPath)

function streamMonitor($param1, $param2) {
    Write-Output $param1
    Write-Output $param2
    }

streamMonitor ($directoryPath, $scriptToRestartPath)
```

And here is a version that just uses one set of parameters.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param ($directoryPath,$scriptToRestartPath)

function streamMonitor {
    Write-Output $directoryPath
    Write-Output $scriptToRestartPath
    }

streamMonitor
```

Comment: While your diagnosis is correct, the suggested solution is unlike to help the OP, as they want to pass arguments from _outside_ the script file.